# Averaging scores in database (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have a database `Result.objects.all()` of around 15 objects. Result has a field called score which ranges from 1-5. So if I preform `q = Result.objecets.get(id=1)`, `q.score` is 2.
What's a method of finding the average of all scores for all 15 objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use django [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) functions to do this;

```
# Average price across all objects.
>>> from django.db.models import Avg
>>> Result.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('score'))
{'score__avg': 34.35}
```

Comment: +1. The best part is that this is done in the database, not in application code, so it's much more scalable. :-)

Comment: Let's knock this up a notch: Is there anyway to ignore all scores that are 2 and only average 1,3,4, and 5? I may have to post a new question.

Comment: you can filter for your objects

Comment: Yea this does it: q = Result.objects.exclude(score=2).aggregate(Avg('score'))